# Imported simple products are not associated with their parent configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9

I have exported all my products using Dataflow - Profiles, and when I try to import these products again using same original CSV file (to a fresh Magento website), all products are imported, but simple products are not associated with their parent configurable products (also when I open one of configurable products, I see 
"Select Configurable Attributes" screen.) My Magento version is 1.9.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Dataflow does not allow to create configurables via import.
Use built-in import/export profile to associate the products with configurable and make sure your file is structured according to Magento requirements.

Comment: I export it and then import the same unchanged file, so I guess it should be 100% correctly structured?